# How to delete all RecyclerView items from SQLite Database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, sql-delete

I am a beginner at coding in Java. I am creating a notes app with lots of other features. And one of the features are, storing the user's bank card details in a RecyclerView. I did this by making an SQLite CRUD. All of the Create, Read, Update and Delete works. And I protected this page with a Pattern lock.

And when we are in the Input Pattern page, we can see a clickable text called **Click HERE if you forgot your pattern**, That works. And when you click on that clickable text, the app shows an Alert Dialog, titled **are you sure?** and the message is **If you change your pattern, all your data will be deleted** then there are two buttons **Yes** and **No**. No does nothing, it just cancel the forgot pattern thing. But the problem is with the Yes button.

When we click it, It should delete all bank cards or delete all data. Please suggest a way to delete all data from the SQLite Database. I tried lots of ways to do this.

**HERE IS MY INPUT PATTERN ACTIVITY**

```
package com.ixidev.simplenotepad;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.ItemTouchHelper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.ixidev.simplenotepad.model.Note;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ProgramActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton fab, fabChangePattern, fabexit;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerViewBC;
    CardsDatabaseHelper cardsDatabaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);

        mRecyclerViewBC = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewBC);
        cardsDatabaseHelper = new CardsDatabaseHelper(this);

        showRecord();

        fabexit = findViewById(R.id.exitProgram);
        fab = findViewById(R.id.addFabButtonBC);
        fabChangePattern = findViewById(R.id.ChangePattern);

        fabexit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        fabChangePattern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramActivity.this, CreatePasswordActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ProgramActivity.this, AddBankCardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("BCeditMode", false);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showRecord() {

        CardAdapter cardAdapter = new CardAdapter(ProgramActivity.this, cardsDatabaseHelper.getAllBCdata(ConstantsCard.BC_C_ADD_TIMESTAMP + " DESC"));
        mRecyclerViewBC.setAdapter(cardAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        showRecord();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**HERE IS MY DATABASE HELPER CLASS**

```
package com.ixidev.simplenotepad;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardsDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public CardsDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
        super(context, ConstantsCard.BC_DB_NAME, null, ConstantsCard.BC_DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(ConstantsCard.BC_CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long insertInfo(String number, String cvv, String expiry, String image, String addTimestamp, String updateTimestamp) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_NUMBER, number);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_CVV, cvv);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_EXPIRY, expiry);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_IMAGE, image);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_ADD_TIMESTAMP, addTimestamp);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, updateTimestamp);

        long id = db.insert(ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
        return id;
    }

    public void updateInfo(String BCid, String number, String cvv, String expiry, String image, String addTimestamp, String updateTimestamp) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_NUMBER, number);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_CVV, cvv);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_EXPIRY, expiry);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_IMAGE, image);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_ADD_TIMESTAMP, addTimestamp);
        values.put(ConstantsCard.BC_C_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP, updateTimestamp);

        db.update(ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME, values, ConstantsCard.BC_C_ID + " = ?", new String[]{BCid});
        db.close();
    }

    public void deleteInfo(String BCid) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME, ConstantsCard.BC_C_ID + " = ? ", new String[]{BCid});
        db.close();
    }

    public void testDelete() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME,null,null);
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("TRUNCATE table " + ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();
    }

    public void delete(String BCid)
    {
        String[] args={BCid};
        getWritableDatabase().delete("texts", "_ID=?", args);
    }

    public ArrayList<CardModel> getAllBCdata(String orderByBC) {

        ArrayList<CardModel> ArrayListCard = new ArrayList<>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME + " ORDER BY " + orderByBC;

        SQLiteDatabase BCdb = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor CardCursor = BCdb.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (CardCursor.moveToNext()) {

            do {
                CardModel cardModel = new CardModel(
                        ""+CardCursor.getInt(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_ID)),
                        ""+CardCursor.getString(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_IMAGE)),
                        ""+CardCursor.getString(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_NUMBER)),
                        ""+CardCursor.getString(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_CVV)),
                        ""+CardCursor.getString(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_EXPIRY)),
                        ""+CardCursor.getString(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_ADD_TIMESTAMP)),
                        ""+CardCursor.getString(CardCursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCard.BC_C_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP))
                );

                ArrayListCard.add(cardModel);
            } while (CardCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        BCdb.close();
        return ArrayListCard;
    }
}
```

**HERE IS MY ADAPTER CLASS**

```
package com.ixidev.simplenotepad;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.arch.core.executor.TaskExecutor;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.Holder> {

    private Context CardContext;
    private ArrayList<CardModel> CardArrayList;
    CardsDatabaseHelper cardsDatabaseHelper;

    public CardAdapter(Context cardContext, ArrayList<CardModel> cardArrayList) {
        CardContext = cardContext;
        CardArrayList = cardArrayList;
        cardsDatabaseHelper = new CardsDatabaseHelper(CardContext);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View viewBC = LayoutInflater.from(CardContext).inflate(R.layout.bc_row, parent, false);

        return new Holder(viewBC);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, int position) {

        CardModel cardModel = CardArrayList.get(position);

        final String BCid = cardModel.getBCid();
        final String BCimage = cardModel.getImageBC();
        final String BCnumber = cardModel.getNumber();
        final String BCcvv = cardModel.getCvv();
        final String BCexpiry = cardModel.getExpiryBC();
        final String addTimeStampBC = cardModel.getAddTimeStampBC();
        final String updateTimeStampBC = cardModel.getUpdateTimeStampBC();

        holder.profileIvBC.setImageURI(Uri.parse(BCimage));
        holder.number.setText(BCnumber);
        holder.cvv.setText(BCcvv);
        holder.expiryBC.setText(BCexpiry);

        holder.editButtonBC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                editDialog(
                  ""+position,
                  ""+BCid,
                  ""+BCnumber,
                  ""+BCcvv,
                  ""+BCexpiry,
                  ""+BCimage,
                  ""+addTimeStampBC,
                  ""+updateTimeStampBC
                );
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                deleteDialog(
                        ""+BCid
                );
                return false;
            }
        });

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(CardContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                cardsDatabaseHelper.testDelete();
                cardsDatabaseHelper.delete(BCid);
            }
        });

    }

    private void deleteDialog(final String BCid) {

       AlertDialog.Builder builderBC = new AlertDialog.Builder(CardContext);
       builderBC.setTitle("Delete?");
       builderBC.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this document?");
       builderBC.setCancelable(false);
       builderBC.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_delete);
       builderBC.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

               cardsDatabaseHelper.deleteInfo(BCid);
               ((ProgramActivity)CardContext).onResume();
               Toast.makeText(CardContext, "Successfully deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

       builderBC.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       });

       builderBC.create().show();
    }

    private void editDialog(String position, String BCid, String BCnumber, String BCcvv, String BCexpiry, String BCimage, String addTimeStampBC, String updateTimeStampBC) {

        AlertDialog.Builder BCbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CardContext);
        BCbuilder.setTitle("Edit?");
        BCbuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to edit this Bank Card?");
        BCbuilder.setCancelable(false);
        BCbuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_edit);

        BCbuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(CardContext, EditBankCardActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("BCID", BCid);
                intent.putExtra("NUMBER", BCnumber);
                intent.putExtra("CVV", BCcvv);
                intent.putExtra("EXPIRYBC", BCexpiry);
                intent.putExtra("IMAGE", BCimage);
                intent.putExtra("BC_ADD_TIMESTAMP", addTimeStampBC);
                intent.putExtra("BC_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP", updateTimeStampBC);
                intent.putExtra("BCeditMode", true);
                CardContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        BCbuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        BCbuilder.create().show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return CardArrayList.size();
    }

    class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView profileIvBC;
        TextView number, cvv, expiryBC;
        ImageButton editButtonBC;

        public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            profileIvBC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileIvBC);
            number = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
            cvv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvv);
            expiryBC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.expiry);
            editButtonBC = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editBtnBC);
        }
    }

}
```

**HERE IS MY MODEL CLASS**

```
package com.ixidev.simplenotepad;

public class CardModel {

    String BCid, imageBC, number, cvv, expiryBC, addTimeStampBC, updateTimeStampBC;

    public CardModel(String BCid, String imageBC, String number, String cvv, String expiryBC, String addTimeStampBC, String updateTimeStampBC) {
        this.BCid = BCid;
        this.imageBC = imageBC;
        this.number = number;
        this.cvv = cvv;
        this.expiryBC = expiryBC;
        this.addTimeStampBC = addTimeStampBC;
        this.updateTimeStampBC = updateTimeStampBC;
    }

    public String getBCid() {
        return BCid;
    }

    public void setBCid(String BCid) {
        this.BCid = BCid;
    }

    public String getImageBC() {
        return imageBC;
    }

    public void setImageBC(String imageBC) {
        this.imageBC = imageBC;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getCvv() {
        return cvv;
    }

    public void setCvv(String cvv) {
        this.cvv = cvv;
    }

    public String getExpiryBC() {
        return expiryBC;
    }

    public void setExpiryBC(String expiryBC) {
        this.expiryBC = expiryBC;
    }

    public String getAddTimeStampBC() {
        return addTimeStampBC;
    }

    public void setAddTimeStampBC(String addTimeStampBC) {
        this.addTimeStampBC = addTimeStampBC;
    }

    public String getUpdateTimeStampBC() {
        return updateTimeStampBC;
    }

    public void setUpdateTimeStampBC(String updateTimeStampBC) {
        this.updateTimeStampBC = updateTimeStampBC;
    }
}
```

And here is my **CONSTANTS** class

```
package com.ixidev.simplenotepad;

public class ConstantsCard {

public static final String BC_DB_NAME = "MY_BANK_CARDS";
public static final int BC_DB_VERSION = 1;
public static final String BC_TABLE_NAME = "MY_BANK_CARDS_TABLE";

public static final String BC_C_ID = "BC_ID";
public static final String BC_C_NUMBER = "BC_NUMBER";
public static final String BC_C_CVV = "BC_CVV";
public static final String BC_C_EXPIRY = "BC_EXPIRY";
public static final String BC_C_IMAGE = "BC_IMAGE";
public static final String BC_C_ADD_TIMESTAMP = "BC_ADD_TIMESTAMP";
public static final String BC_C_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP = "BC_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP";

public static final String BC_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + BC_TABLE_NAME + "("
        + BC_C_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + BC_C_NUMBER + " TEXT,"
        + BC_C_CVV + " TEXT,"
        + BC_C_EXPIRY + " TEXT,"
        + BC_C_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
        + BC_C_ADD_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT,"
        + BC_C_UPDATE_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT"
        + ");";
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are using `TRUNCATE` to erase your table. What problem are you having with that?

Comment: OH! That was just a tutorial i followed which did not work for me just ignore that

Comment: Well, sure, it didn't work - isn't that the whole point of your question? If it does not work we can't ignore it - you want to find out _why_ it doesn't work.

Comment: Is `testDelete()` the method we should be looking at?

Comment: i just made testDelete() to test a tutorial

Comment: yes please, tell me what to do in test delete, then I will copy the contents from that method and paste it in a different method where i want it

Comment: The way Stack Overflow works is that you write the code, and if it does not work, then you tell us what's wrong. So, you have two calls in `testDelete()` - one that just uses `DELETE` and the other uses `TRUNCATE`. Pick one, put it in your actual method, and see if it works. If it does not, please provide the stack trace.

Comment: TRUNCATE does'nt work

Comment: neither does DELETE

Comment: OK, can you expand on "doesn't work"? Let's just concentrate on the `DELETE` version for the moment. Do you expect the return value of `db.execSQL("delete from "+ ConstantsCard.BC_TABLE_NAME);` to be true for success, false for failure? Check the docs please. If this is the case, then log what this value is. Is it true or false?

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand you. Ok, i will expand on does'nt work, when i click yes, it works but does'nt delete the data. I tried on TRUNCATE too, then also the same thing happens

Comment: Please log the return value from `db.execSQL()`, and let us know what it is. Am I correct in believing this will return `true` if the statement is successful?

Comment: it returns true

Comment: Could you replace the shown code with what you have now? I believe you have modified your copy of the code since you posted it.

Comment: Your `execSQL()` should not return true, [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)) show that it should return void, i.e. nothing at all. The docs also recommend you should use [the delete method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) with a null WHERE clause. Try that instead.

Comment: hi I got it fixed